# What is the typical owner:group for Craft files and folders?

Tags: permissions

Using cpanel, apache. All requirements are met for Craft. On a typical default set up I believe that the public_html is user:nobody. What should the `../craft` folder owner and group be? With what permissions? What about sub folders?

I  getting 403 forbidden with `0744` and `0774` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your hosting environment, but the article [Hardening Craft CMS Permissions](https://nystudio107.com/blog/hardening-craft-cms-permissions) might be useful to you.